# Why in unanswered questions there are answered questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Is it really normal to find answered questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/unanswered) ?

Look at this :[this http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/839455uns.png](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/839455uns.png)

Shadock

Comment: Presumably this will be moved to meta. I'll note that currently for me that link includes a question with an accepted answer, even.

Comment: For some basic info see also [this tag-wiki](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/unanswered-questions/info).

Comment: *Why in unanswered questions there are answered questions?* - To shock and confuse unsuspecting users.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image]

> questions **with no upvoted or accepted answers**

Comment: Whoa. This site has a sidebar?

Comment: I never saw it XD

Comment: rule: the larger and redder something is, the less it gets noticed.

Comment: No, here is an example of a bad UI. The title says "Unanswered questions". Why would anybody expect users to read the sidebar, if they already have the info (but wrong info) in the title?

Comment: This is the only page I remember that its title in the sidebar. Maybe you should put it in the footer? And than say "well, everything is written in the footer, can't you see it, it is even in bold, and red, for you stupid guys that do not expect title in the footer"? lol

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, a question appears in the "unanswered" queue when it has no answers, or if when it has answers, none of them has a positive score and none is accepted.

(For future reference: this kind of question is better received in meta.)

Comment: In meta maths ? :O

Comment: Makes sense. I edited my answer :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think that the question needs a non-negative score as well.

Comment: You are correct, @Asaf.